# Testing and Deploying a Solidity Contract on Ethereum - Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract address

Tags: solidity, javascript, uniswap

Having trouble testing the following code as I get the following error in the photo: "Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account"
[image]

According to the error, the issue seems to be the line  `amountOut = swapRouter.exactInput(params);`, which is in in the function swapExactInputMultihop (within SwapExamples.sol), but I cannot seem to figure out exactly what it is. Any help on solving this is appreciated.

The Solidity code (SwapExamples.sol) is:

```
contract SwapExamples {
    ISwapRouter public constant swapRouter = ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);

    address public constant UNI = 0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984;   
    address public constant DAI = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;   
    address public constant WETH9 = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;  

    uint24 public constant poolFee = 3000;

    function swapExactInputMultihop(uint256 amountIn) external returns (uint256 amountOut) {
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(WETH9, msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(WETH9, address(swapRouter), amountIn);

        ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams memory params =
            ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams({
                path: abi.encodePacked(WETH9, poolFee, UNI, poolFee, DAI),
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: 0
            });
        amountOut = swapRouter.exactInput(params); // Executes the swap.
    }
}
```

The test file swap.test.js:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("SwapExamples", function () {
  it("Should Deploy SwapExamples and make a swapExactInputMultihop swap", async function () {
    const DAI = "0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa";
    const WETH9 = "0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C";
    const UNI = "0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984";

    const SwapExamples = await ethers.getContractFactory("SwapExamples");
    const swapExamples = await SwapExamples.deploy();
    await swapExamples.deployed();

    swapExamplesAddress = swapExamples.address;

    let WETH9Contract = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", WETH9);

    const approvalAmount = BigInt(0.05 * (10 ** 18));
    let approvalRequesst = await WETH9Contract.approve(swapExamples.address, approvalAmount);
    await approvalRequesst.wait();

    console.log(approvalRequesst)
    let swapExactInputMultihop = await swapExamples.swapExactInputMultihop(approvalAmount);
    await swapExactInputMultihop.wait();
    await swapExactInputMultihop.swapExactMultiHop(approvalRequesst.address) 
    console.log("appro: ", approvalRequesst)
    console.log("swapExactInputMultihop: ", swapExactInputMultihop)
  });
});
```

And finally, hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

const ALCHEMY_API_KEY = "xxxxxxx" // Placeholder. I filled in correctly on my code
const GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY = "xxxxxxx" // Placeholder. I filled in correctly on my code

module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.8.0",
      },
      {
        version: "0.7.6",
        settings: {}
      }
    ]
  },
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: `https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some of your addresses are wrong. 0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C and 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa aren't contracts on goerli

Comment: Corrected the Goerli addresses, but I am still getting a similar error:

                       
   "Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account
   at SwapExamples.swapExactInputMultihop (contracts/SwapExamples.sol:75)..."